# mysql group_concat

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables.

**products**

```
id  title      image_ids
---------------------
1   myproduct  1,2,3
```

**images**

```
id  title     file_name
-------------------------
1   myimage   myimage.jpg
2   myimage2  myimage2.jpg
3   myimage3  myimage3.jpg
```

I want to query so that the names of the images are concatenated into a single field for each product reference.

This query doesn't work

```
   SELECT products.title,
          products.image_ids,
          GROUP_CONCAT(images.file_name)
     FROM products
LEFT JOIN images ON images.id IN (products.image_ids)
    WHERE products.id = 1
    GROUP BY products.id
```

This one does:

```
   SELECT products.title,
          products.image_ids,
          GROUP_CONCAT(images.file_name)
     FROM products
LEFT JOIN images ON images.id IN (1,2,3)
    WHERE products.id = 1
    GROUP BY products.id
```

And produces the desired results

```
title       image_ids  file_names
--------------------------------------------------------------
myproduct   1,2,3      myimage.jpg,myimage2.jpg,myimage3.jpg
```

Why doesn't the first query work when it is asking the same thing as the second query and how can I make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` does not work for comma-separated lists of values.

Basically, you are not comparing integers, you are comparing strings:

```
SELECT  1 IN (1, 2, 3) -- True
SELECT  1 IN ('1, 2, 3') -- False ('1' <> '1, 2, 3')
```

Use `FIND_IN_SET` instead:

```
SELECT  products.title,products.image_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(images.file_name)
FROM    products
LEFT JOIN
        images
ON      FIND_IN_SET(images.id, products.image_ids)
WHERE   products.id = 1
GROUP BY
        products.id
```

This, however, is not the best solution performance-wise since `FIND_IN_SET` is non-sargable. It will require a full table scan on `images`.

If you have some reasonable limit on the number of values in `products.image_ids` (say, no more than `5` images per product), you can use this query instead:

```
SELECT  products.title,products.image_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(images.file_name)
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3 AS n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4 AS n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5 AS n
        ) q
CROSS JOIN
        products
LEFT JOIN
        images
ON      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_ids, ',', n), ',', 1)
WHERE   products.id = 1
        AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_ids, ',', n) <> SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_ids, ',', n - 1)
GROUP BY
        products.id
```

Comment: (From wikipedia) In relational databases, a condition (or predicate) in a query is said to be sargable if the DBMS engine can take advantage of an index to speed up the execution of the query (using index seeks, not covering indexes). The term is derived from a contraction of Search ARGument Able.